# Print with camel-printer in IP printer

Tags: printing, apache-camel

I would like to send a document i am creating to an IP printer. I would like to ask if this is possible with the **camel-printer** component?

I am asking because PrinterProducer uses the PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices() in order to find a printer. This will return a PrintService[] which are actually the printers that are set in our local system. If this is true, how can we send a print to an IP printer that is not register in our system and it is located somewhere on the net?

I tried

```
<to uri="lpr://192.168.xxx.xxx"/>
```

but I am getting an error in the PrinterConfiguration when it tries to strart the component. `String index out of range: 0`

Is it possible to send a print to an IP printer which is not registered in our system with camel-printer?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `lpr://192.168.xxx.xxx` on its own, is not a valid URI for an lpr endpoint. See the camel-printer documentation here:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.x/components/camel-printer/src/main/docs/lpr-component.adoc#uri-format

You need to specify the printer name or path to the printer. E.g:

```
<to uri="lpr://192.168.1.100/myprinter"/>
```

Comment: Yes you are right about the uri, i made a typo there. But even if you put the IP and the printer name, you cannot create the endpoint because it looks us for locally printers that are set up in the local machine.

`org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[lpr://192.168.1.100/myprinter]. Reason: javax.print.PrintException: No printer found with name: 192.168.1.100/myprinter. Please verify that the host and printer are registered and reachable from this machine.`